# Multiple lines of input in <input type="text" />

Tags: html

I have this text input in a form:

```
<input type="text"
       cols="40" 
       rows="5" 
       style="width:200px; height:50px;" 
       name="Text1" 
       id="Text1" 
       value="" />
```

I am trying to get it to take multiple lines of input. The width and height make the box to be bigger, but the user can enter text all (s)he wants yet it fills one line only.

How do I make the input more like a textarea?

Answer (score 931, accepted):

You need to use a textarea to get multiline handling.

```html
<textarea name="Text1" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Comment: Yes, but, `textarea` doesn't support the `pattern` attribute. So darn.

Comment: hmmmm, what. Im looking for multiple insert for type text. why this people ask this ques.

Comment: @AlexH your comment is **very** important and helpful indeed, thanks.

Comment: what I don't like about this is that in JQuery, you can't set textarea value using `val()`. You have to `append` to it. :(

Comment: @AlexH: You could remove your comment and add it again if you want to alter anything.

Answer (score 79):

You can't. At the time of writing, the only HTML form element that's designed to be multi-line is [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/textarea).

Answer (score 68):

It is possible to make a text-input multi-line by giving it the `word-break: break-word;` attribute. (Only tested this in Chrome)

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that Chrome was allowing multiple lines for inputs, which I totally didn't want to, and the reason was word-break which was inherited from the body element

Comment: Looks good in Chrome 39 and Safari 8.0.2, but not Firefox 34 in my brief testing. :( http://jsfiddle.net/msybs9g7/

Comment: This solution is outdated and not supported in most browsers anymore. Use <textarea> instead

Answer (score 63):

Use the textarea

```
<textarea name="textarea" style="width:250px;height:150px;"></textarea>
```

don't leave any space between the opening and closing tags Or Else This will leave some empty lines or spaces.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if the height would work instead of rows.

Answer (score 42):

If you need **Multiline Textarea** with **Auto Height Increase** feature, You can use **following simple javascript**,

```js
function auto_height(elem) {  /* javascript */
    elem.style.height = '1px';
    elem.style.height = `${elem.scrollHeight}px`;
}
```

```css
.auto_height { /* CSS */
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="1" class="auto_height" onInput="auto_height(this)"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks. I modified this and used it in my react textarea

Comment: P.S you want to add overflow: hidden to the textarea, or else it will add the extra height few letters before the actual needed one.

Comment: For me this caused the textarea to slightly increase in height when you start typing. A workaround is to set padding to 0 and restore it after setting the height: https://codepen.io/mrexodia/pen/LYdrBqM

Comment: Probably nered a `ResizeObserver` too for if the window is size changed

Comment: in react.js I applied it and it worked.

Comment: The Codepen from @mrexodia is a perfect solution, thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Check this:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.7

> The  TEXTAREA element creates a 
>   multi-line text input control

Answer (score 14):

You should use `textarea` to support multiple-line inputs.

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
Here you can write some text to display in the textarea as the default text
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `<div contenteditable="true">` ([supported well](https://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable)) with storing to `<input type="hidden">`.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="multilineinput" contenteditable="true"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="detailsfield" name="detailsfield">
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#multilineinput").on('keyup',function(e) {   
    $("#detailsfield").val($(this).text()); //store content to input[type=hidden]
});
//optional - one line but wrap it
$("#multilineinput").on('keypress',function(e) {    
    if(e.which == 13) { //on enter
        e.preventDefault(); //disallow newlines     
        // here comes your code to submit
    }
});
```

Answer (score -6):

If you're using React, you could use the 3rd-party UI library [MUI](https://mui.com/). It has a custom proprietary `<Input>` element with a `multiline` option.

As LSE commented, ultimately it gets rendered as `<textarea>`.

```
  <FormControl>
    <InputLabel htmlFor="textContract">{`textContract`}</InputLabel>
    <Input
      id="textContract"
      multiline
      rows="30"
      type="text"
      value={props.textContract}
      onChange={() => {}}
    />
  </FormControl>
```

https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#multiline

Comment: From the documentation : `The multiline prop transforms the text field into a <textarea> element.`. So even though it looks like an <input>, it's rendering a <textarea>.

Answer (score -10):

If you don't need to edit it, you can use a

```html
<span>text here</span>
```

It will expand with the text.

Comment: This would remove the input element completely; doesn't help at all.