# Input text stuck in center of input

Tags: html, forms, css

I'm having an issue getting the text in one of my input boxes to begin at the top of the input box. Instead, it is vertically centered. None of the other solutions on stackoverflow seemed to help.

I've recreated the issue here (ignore how bad the rest of the form looks ;): http://codepen.io/tim1017/pen/ofuhx

And here's the actual page it's located on: http://dev.longviewsources.com/contact/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an input where you should use a textarea. Input elements only support one line of input, thus it is centering that one line vertically. Here's a working fork: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LBvsd

Answer (score 3):

For multi-line text, which it looks like you're going for, you probably want to use a `<textarea>`, not a text input tag.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Also see: [Multiple lines of input in <input type="text" />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262472/multiple-lines-in-input-type-text)

Answer (score 0):

corrected and forked you can check the css and example;
    [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jpvGm)

Comment: how is that fixes his problem?