# Scrollable <input> Using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to have a scrollable `<input>` for an address to be entered so it need to allow the enter key to also be pressed to move to the next line.

Whats the best way of doing this using CSS, inline styling, HTML etc

I have looked on Google and Bootstrap site but I can seem to find anything to accommodate this.

I do NOT want any Jquery/Java etc please

Comment: Why not use `<textarea>` ? The `<textarea>` tag defines a multi-line text input control.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple lines of input in <input type="text" />](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262472/multiple-lines-of-input-in-input-type-text)

Comment: @ArturKäpp thanks for this.  For the life of me I couldn't remember of find anything

Comment: @DavidG thanks for this.  For the life of me I couldn't remember of find anything