# How to auto resize an input field vertically and not horizontally like Facebook by pressing typing or pressing Shift and Enter

Tags: jquery, css

I have found many plugins that allow a textarea to be resized [vertically](http://unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/)  and other plugins that allow an input field to be resized horizontally but I have not found one that allows an input field to be resized vertically like Facebook does for it's comment system

How do I resize an input field vertically when the text reaches the end of the input so that the text may go to the next line just like Facebook does with it's comment system ? And how to resize the text also when the shift and enter keys are pressed just like on Facebook ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262472/multiple-lines-of-input-in-input-type-text

Comment: Also you would get a better reaction if you posted code and show you tried something.

Comment: Consider using a `textarea` rather than a `text` `input`.

Comment: @floor that link is also about a textarea. I am looking for something with an input not a textareas

Comment: @FerdineFaithfull if you read through all the answers you would have found the one that talks about using inputs instead of textareas.

Comment: @floor I read through twice. The question was about an input but the answers are about textareas instead of input

Comment: @FerdineFaithfull I post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out here: [Multiple lines of input in <input type="text" />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262472/multiple-lines-of-input-in-input-type-text)

If you read the 3rd answer from the top by Sté. He goes over how one might implement a multi-line input box.

"It is possible to make a text-input multi-line by giving it the word-break: break-word; attribute."

Then in the comments there is a link to a functional fiddle outlining a simple implementation one could use.  [Jeremy Wadhams Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msybs9g7/)

CSS:

```
input {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;  
  white-space: pre;
  word-break: break-word; 
}
```

HTML:

```
 <input type="text" name="a" id="a" value="bla bla bla bla bla" />
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('a').value = 'Am I \n on a new line?';
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is now outdated - the fiddle no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fairly well. Using a text area you can specify the number of rows and columns it has, then manipulate those with jQuery.

```
<!-- Looks identical to a text input -->
<textarea cols="1"></textarea>
```

Now, each time the key is released, a new row will be added for every 20 characters typed.

```
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
    var rows = $(this).attr('rows'),
        cols = $(this).attr('cols') || 20, // The number of cols is 20 by default
        length = $(this).val().length;

    // After 20 characters are typed, add a new row to the textarea
    if (length % cols === 0) {
      $(this).attr('rows', ++rows);
    }
});
```

Comment: all these are textarea. I am looking for a working solution with input not textarea

Answer (score -1):

When a key is pressed, set the height of the textarea to its `scrollHeight`, like this:

```
input.onkeydown = function() {
    input.style.height = input.scrollHeight + "px";
}
```

The scrollheight is always the height of the contents, so this will make the textarea expand to its contents.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z1wkcmkv/)

**Update:** apparently, webkit calculates the `scrollHeight`as the height of the containing element plus 4px. You can subtract 4px from the `scrollHeight`on each calculation ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pgkan6oz/)), but this won't cause the box to shrink when text is removed.

Comment: That is not working, the height is increasing with every press of a key, even if the text has not begun wrapping.