# How do I include multiple lines within a single textbox?

Tags: css, textbox, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following textbox in an MVC6 form.

```
 <input type="text" asp-for="EmptyTask.TaskDetails" placeholder="New Task" class="txt-newTask" />
```

And the following CSS:

```
.txt-newTask{
height: 150px;
min-width: 400px;
max-width: 400px;
}
```

This appears as such:

[image: Textbox]

The "New Task" text appears in the center of the textbox, and continues off the right hand edge if I continue typing.

My goal is to have a single textbox that stretches across multiple lines within that same box.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Use textarea instead of input element?

Comment: you can use textarea. [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262472/multiple-lines-of-input-in-input-type-text)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need multi line text, you should consider using [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea). which is a control designed for this requirement.

There is an mvc [textarea tag helper](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers/TextAreaTagHelper.cs) so you can use the `asp-for` with the textarea like you did with your input field.

```
<textarea  asp-for="EmptyTask.TaskDetail" class="txt-newTask" 
                                                    placeholder="Enter task"></textarea>
```