# Setting height on form and placeholder break

Tags: html, css

I would like to set the height on this form-group. The problem is that the placeholder can't be more wide that it is now, and therefore I have to make it higher. As it is now the placeholder text is going horizontal out, and I would like the placeholder text continued under the line vertically instead.

Is that possible at all?

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="sr-only" for="udfordring">Største udfordring</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="udfordring" name="udfordring" placeholder="This is a long text there cannot be in the normal field" style="height:300px;"/>
</div>
```

Comment: what element do you have?

Comment: Shoot I am sorry. I copied paste the wrong one. This is the element.

Comment: then you need `textarea` element: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262472/multiple-lines-of-input-in-input-type-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.navbar .navbar-form 
{
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel panel-primary shadow">
  <div class="panel-heading">SUBSCRIBE FOR NEWSLETTER OF WHOLE 10</div> <!-- id-2 for the subscribe channel-->
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form>
        <div class="form group">
      <label for="input e-mail">EMAIL</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form group">
      <label for="input e-mail">USERNAME</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="username">
    </div>

<br>
      <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox">REMEMBER ME</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">LOGIN</button>
  </form>`enter code here`

</div>
</div>
```