# how to make user's input begin at the top and wrap inside the field (this is an html form)

Tags: html, css, forms

This is the current look of my input field:

[image: Sreenshot]
[image: Screenshot 2]

If I begin to type, my text is right in the middle of the box and continues to go to the right forever. I want to make it stop overflowing and do down to a new line each time it reaches the maximum width I have set, and have the text start from the top instead of the middle. I would like to look like word wrap.

Just to mention: I have multiple `input type="text"` fields, so for this one, in particular, I am using its `id="description"` and `#description` respectively.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple lines of input in <input type="text" />](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262472/multiple-lines-of-input-in-input-type-text)

Comment: You deleted a question to which I wanted to comment, and this is the only way to reach you. You say that you are distributing an .exe to your customers that depends on iText. You want to distribute that .exe and ONLY that .exe. Please be aware that this is not sufficient. You also have to distribute the full source code of iText *as well as your source code*. If you don't do this, you are in violation with the AGPL and you can't use iText as an open source library. If you don't want to distribute your source code, you have to buy a commercial license.

Answer (score 3):

Use `<textarea>` tag:

```
<textarea id="description" rows="1" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<input type="text">`, use `<textarea>`. It solves your problem. `<textarea>` is the best solution for this. Visit this link for more info. [textarea](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)