# wordwrap and pattern atributes not working on my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am building an website and I am using this [autocomplete jquery](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#maxheight) I wanted the long words (words longer than the input field is, to break to the next line, or let user to brake them with ENTER key. I tried this code:

```
.wordwrap { 
   white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}
```

but with no result, it doesent brake, it just hides, rest of the word which is longer than the input field.

The second thing I wanted is to allow only words starting with particular character. In this case I choose the letter "ch" or "Ch" I tried to make it with "pattern" parameter but it doesnt work too...

```
<input id="tags" pattern="ch+" required>
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fm0r0dmt/

And textarea doesn't support the pattern attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple lines of input in <input type="text" />](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262472/multiple-lines-of-input-in-input-type-text)

Comment: The ansver have comment that textarea doesn't support the pattern attribute...

Comment: The other way to handle it is with a hidden input field and a span that updates, I'll update my answer to include an example of that.

Answer (score 0):

The `<input />` attribute doesn't support multiline formatting. If you want to break long entries to the next line, you'll have to use a `<textarea></textarea>`

For an example of a custom field that uses an `input` element but supports multiline, check out the code sample attached. For this example, the loop is unnecessary since there's only one input, but it's set up to function like a component so that more than one can be used on the same page.

```js
function createCustomInput(elem){
  var input = elem.querySelector('input'),
      output = elem.querySelector('span')

  input.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    output.textContent = this.value
  })

  output.addEventListener('click', function(){
    input.focus()
  })
}

var customInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.customInput'),
    len = customInputs.length

while(--len > -1){
  createCustomInput(customInputs[len])
}
```

```css
.customInput {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 20px;
}
.customInput span, .customInput input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.customInput span {
  white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
  white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
  word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}
.customInput input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="customInput">
  <input type="text" pattern="ch+">
  <span></span>
</div>
```