# input type text value into multiple lines

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to allow multiple line texts for input `type=text`?

For example, I have text called **"my name is krishna and I am  new to here"**

This is the input text value I want to display in multiple lines.

Like :

```html
myname is krishna </br>
and I am new to here
```

I have tried

```
 word-wrap: break-word;
 word-break: break-all;
 white-space: pre-wrap;
```

Would need some ideas to do this. How can we achieve input type is text wrapping into multiple lines.

Comment: Have you thought of textarea? They work the same way

Comment: you can't do this with input type="text". As mentionned, textarea is the only way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple lines of input in <input type="text" />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262472/multiple-lines-of-input-in-input-type-text)

Comment: but i am using wordpress contact form 7 dynamic text , so it is type text only, any possibility to do with text

Comment: @krishna check my answer. I input some code in Contact form 7 for you

Answer (score 0):

Use a textarea to handle multiple line span

```
<textarea id="someId" name="someName" cols="20" rows="6"></textarea>
```

and then jQuery to get the formatting

```
var htmlCode = $("#someId").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should properly look into textarea. Both of them works the same way.

```
<textarea cols="5" rows="20"></textarea>
```

It also allows you to control the number of cols and rows of the input

If you are using contactform7, this is the shorthand code to include.

```
[textarea your-message 40x10 "your message here ..."]
```

More can be found [Here](https://contactform7.com/text-fields/)