# How to get two row data in same input field of form in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to develop this kind of form field using bootstrap, css and jquery but not able to do it. Any help will be appreciated[two-row input text in same field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuBfp.jpg). Thanks

Comment: share your work so far

Comment: I am sorry but the code is so big and if I snip it, it will won't work properly... I only need two rows in the single input field of the form. or even the side green validation also need help with

Comment: do you have a link to that example?

Comment: it is just this image i got and have to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out this snippet. I have used border-left in order to implement this..

```css
input[type=text],
#textarea {
  border-left: 6px solid green;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
  <label>Username</label>
  <div class="form-group">

    <input type="text" multiple class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required>
    <br>
    <textarea id="textarea" name="Text" class="form-control" cols="40" rows="2" placeholder="Text Area"></textarea>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much... Is there any way we can add that two row in single input field?

Comment: check now added it. If this helps, please put a tick to the answer

Comment: Thank you bro...you are a savior

Comment: sorry but it should not be in textarea. it should be in the input field only

Comment: Input field only have one row. That's why text area there. So you can define more rows as you wish. It is not possible to have multiple lines in input text field. For more info
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262472/multiple-lines-of-input-in-input-type-text/6262536

Comment: you can adjust the height if the input field for two rows as edited in the above answer