# How to make an input field have multiple rows

Tags: html, css

I have a page to edit some settings and then send the new data off in a form to be added etc.

In some of the fields there's quite a bit of writing so just the one line is sometimes not enough and it looks messy.

How can I add multiple rows/lines to an input such as

```
<input type="text" name="site_notes" rows="5" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $site_notes; ?>">
```

As you can see I already tried rows= and it didn't work. I'm aware of textarea but as I was reading about it I saw you cannot have a value in textarea which is even more problematic.

Are there any workarounds to this?

Comment: "'m aware of textarea but as I was reading about it I saw you cannot have a value in textarea which is even more problematic."  - what do you mean exactly?  Can you link to where you read this?  A textarea is exactly made for the purpose of handling multi-line data input.

Comment: look at this example of the textarea from the docs - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Comment: @jusopi On here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp there is no "value" attribute - I need my input/textarea to be able to hold a value (pre-loaded) for editing whilst having multiple rows

Comment: possible duplicate [Multiple lines of input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262472/multiple-lines-of-input-in-input-type-text)

Comment: @David yes I understand that.  See the answer below.  Textareas are handled differently in terms of being preloaded with content.  In terms of accessing the formdata, you still access that the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a few comments for you but I think I understand now what you meant when you said:

> I'm aware of textarea but as I was reading about it I saw you cannot have a value in textarea which is even more problematic

Don't give up on the Textarea.  It is made exactly for multiple rows.  I think you just had the data in the wrong place.  Instead of:

```
<textarea type="text" 
          name="site_notes" 
          rows="5" 
          class="form-control" 
          value="<?php echo $site_notes; ?>">
```

You need to put the value as a child of the textarea:

```
<textarea type="text" 
          name="site_notes" 
          rows="5" 
          class="form-control">  

    <?php echo $site_notes; ?>
</textarea>
```