# How to have a line break in input type = "text"

Tags: html

[image]

Is  there any way I can make the Description box become into two lines box instead of a single line block?

```
<label>Description</label>
<input type="text" name="description" size="50" required class="input" placeholder="Enter the description of the product">
```

Comment: No you can't. If you need line breaks in your input, use `<textarea>`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262472/multiple-lines-of-input-in-input-type-text
have a look here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately HTML doesn't allow you to make an input multi-line but you can use a textarea instead. (See the code snippet below)
I've set "rows" to 2 since you mentioned you wanted it to take 2 lines instead of just 1, you can change that to be whatever number of lines you want.

```
<form action="/form/submit" method="post">
   <label for="text">Description:</label>
   <br>
   <textarea id="text" name="text" rows="2" cols="50"></textarea>
   <br/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should use Textarea while inserting data and when you want to show/echo the data use this PHP function to preserve the line breaks echo nl2br($string);

For example

```
    <textarea class="form-control" name="short_desc" required></textarea>
```

and for frontend echo use following function

```
<?PHP echo nl2br($short_desc);?>
```

It will preserve the line break and show content with breaks on frontend,

Also keep the Mysql data type text for it.