# Is that possible to next line in Input tag in html css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, input

I have an input tag, when i am typing in input, after a given width the text is overflow hidden.. What actully i need is when I am typing in input the text goes to next line, Is that **possible**. only input not textarea.

```css
    input {
        height: auto;
    
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The input element</h1>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="text"  id="comment" name="comment" /><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Click the "Submit" button and the form-data will be sent to a page on the 
server called "action_page.php".</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple lines of input in <input type="text" />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262472/multiple-lines-of-input-in-input-type-text)

Comment: @Shahab Khan No, why is a `textarea` not good?

Comment: Can't you just make it wider with js? do you really need multiple lines

Comment: Okay, I will use textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
autosize(document.getElementById("comment"));
```

```css
#comment{
    resize: none;
    height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The input element</h1>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <textarea id="comment" name="comment"></textarea><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Click the "Submit" button and the form-data will be sent to a page on the 
server called "action_page.php".</p>

</body>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jackmoore/autosize/master/dist/autosize.min.js"></script>
</html>
```