# I changed my textbox size now my textbox's text position is not correct

Tags: html, css

This is how my [texbox](https://ibb.co/RprpRYf)

This is how I wanted it to look [like](https://ibb.co/L0HW5WH)

This is my HTML script

```css
body {
    background-color: grey;
}

#myquestion {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 1.3mm;
    border-top: grey;
    border-left: grey;
    height: 70mm;
    width: 100mm;
    }

#mybutton {
    background-color: lightblue;
    border-radius: 1.3mm;
    border-right: grey;
    border-bottom: grey;
}
```

```html
    <label>Enter your question:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="myquestion"><br>
    <button type="button" id="mybutton">Submit</button>
```

Please help me fix this. I really want to finish my project today since it's a really easy project but I'm new at HTML and CSS and JavaScript so I really hope you can help me!

Comment: You can use <textarea> tag like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262472/multiple-lines-of-input-in-input-type-text

Comment: You can use `textarea` as @GamerInTheGame mentioned. Or if you still wanna use input, you can use a `pseudo class` to show the `placeholder` text inside the input any place you want by providing `position absolute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the default value of an `input` tag is `vertical-align: middle`, to make what you want just change

`<input type="text" id="myquestion">`

to

`<textarea type="text" id="myquestion"></textarea>`

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
    background-color: grey;
}

#myquestion {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 1.3mm;
    border-top: grey;
    border-left: grey;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 300px;
    }

#mybutton {
    background-color: lightblue;
    border-radius: 1.3mm;
    border-right: grey;
    border-bottom: grey;
}
```

```html
<label>Enter your question:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="myquestion"><br>
    <button type="button" id="mybutton">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your `<input>` element into a multi-line `<textarea>`.

Answer (score 0):

Give input box a id like

```
   <label>Enter your question:</label><br>
    <div id="myquestion1"><input type="text" id="myquestion"></div><br>
    <button type="button" id="mybutton">Submit</button>
```

and replace your css with the following

```
body {
    background-color: grey;
}
 #myquestion1 {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 1.3mm;
    border-top: grey;
    border-left: grey;
    height: 70mm;
    width: 100mm;
}
input#myquestion {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 1.3mm;
    border-top: grey;
    border-left: grey;
    border-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
}



#mybutton {
    background-color: lightblue;
    border-radius: 1.3mm;
    border-right: grey;
    border-bottom: grey;
}
```